# McMullen's polytope algebra

Tags: polytopes, convex-cone

Does the multiplication of McMullen's polytope algebra still work for (polyhedral) cones, making it into a ring?

See McMullen's paper [The polytope algebra](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(89)90029-7) for definitions.